# PVC Sleepers - Finished Basement Subfloor

Tags: basement, flooring, subfloor, basement-refinishing

I came over here from reddit because I really want some feedback on this idea I stole from another redditor (they haven't responded to my inquiries, but I really like the idea).

I'm currently planning to finish my basement. The first major hurdle is leveling the concrete floor. I've looked into self leveling concrete, but ruled that out due to the volume, effort, and significant cost involved in going that route.

That leads me to sleeper floors. My floor is very uneven. This isn't due to heaving or cracking, it honestly just looks like a bad pour since the surface of the concrete itself isn't even all that smooth. Rip cutting a bunch of sleepers that would sit level over all the undulations seems like a chore.

Another poster a few months back mentioned using 3" pvc pipe cut into rings of various thickness and glued to the floor in a large grid pattern worked well as sleepers. This sounds like it would be easy: set up the laser level, set the end of the pipe on the floor, mark and cut the pvc at the laser intersect, glue it down, move a foot or so over and repeat. Then lay osb over the grid.

Somebody tell me why this is a bad idea? What am I missing?

TL;DR, can I use PVC rings of varying thickness as leveling sleepers directly under OSB subfloor in a finished basement?

Comment: I've seen this method used on concrete paver patios on multistory condo buildings, worked excellent.

Comment: I wouldn't do it but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you both. Rohit, I hear you. It sounds like such a redneck idea, but I just can't think of a reason not to.  Matt, I've actually seen a product specifically made for that application (they're basically telescopic pedestals), but they're a bit too thick for my application. But the concept is the same, which makes me think it should be viable. It's not like I'm going to be throwing 1000's of lbs. on this floor either.

Comment: There are plenty of fine solutions to raising a level basement floor. All of them require a tireless eye for detail, careful precision, and tedious tweaks to get it right. Even the slightest belly or bow will cause the OSB to rock back and forth mercilessly. I hope your flooring choice will handle deflection well.

Comment: Popham, that is the type of analytical breakdown I was hoping for. Do you think the 12" grid is overkill and I could possibly get away with 16"? Thank you for the breakdown! Thank you for the reply AdamO, it will be carpet throughout. The plan is to anchor the OSB the osb with some longer Tapcons to reach the concrete with plenty of bite. Hopefully that minimizes some of the movement.

Comment: What kind of finished flooring are you ultimately planning on?

Comment: Huesmann, just carpet floor. I'm just trying to get it off the concrete and level it out. The entire floor varies about 2 inches in elevation throughout the basement. Not terrible.  The problem is that those variations are scattered and the floor is wavy.

Comment: What happens if you have water ingress in the space occupied by these PVC rings? How would you dry it out?

Comment: What is your ceiling height going to be? Would you like to have the ceiling as high as possible, i.e., how close to 8' are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Jim.  I should have mentioned there will be a vapor barrier down as well. Water ingress shouldn't be a problem. The open area under the subfloor and vapor barrier should be sufficient to handle any possible moisture. But that issue would apply to any floor in any finished basement. I don't think it would be a unique problem only encountered using PVC rings.  Ceilings are 7 ft. We will be leaving the ceiling open to the joists above. In aware this is low, but I'm fine with it.

Comment: The water ingress I was thinking about would be a plumbing leak leading to a flood. This would be either the water supply or a sewer backup and overflow.  Also surface waters outside leaking into a basement. It is true that the standard support of ripped 2x4 joists on 16", 19", or 24" centers resting on the floor would present a problem for achieving drying after a flood, but at least those provide a nailing member for the subfloor sheets. How do you plan to join and secure the 4x8' sheets of subfloor? When ceiling height allows it, 2x4 joists could be lifted above the concrete by PT blocks.

Comment: Another possibility to support sleepers on an uneven floor would be polypropylene wedges plus PP or pressure treated (PT) shims in the really low spots. A pair of matched shims with one driven from each side could support the 2x4 joists every 2'. This would provide a clear air path under the floor so the space could be dried if necessary with a shop vac pulling through a  hole on one edge and two or 3 or 4 holes in the corners. But you probably do not have the head clearance for all this. I think you should fill and level with floor leveler. .

Comment: Hi Jim, definitely good for thought. I just measured again to be sure, my lowest spot is 1.875 inches below my highest spot. With .71 inches of subfloor and my pvc, that would give me 2.6 inches. If I use 3.75" tapcons, that should give me a minimum of 1" embedment in the absolute lowest spots. Not great, but that depth is only in a small area.  No matter what I do, I definitely want to preserve as much ceiling height as possible.

Comment: @Geologist1986, you said the magic number, 7'-0", so I figure that you already know. In case you don't, though, the IRC requires 7'-0" ceilings for habitable spaces. Keep it taller than 7'-0" if you want the space officially categorized as a sleeping room, hallway, or a kitchen. Flat instead of level can be good enough.

Comment: Hi popham, yes, I've already accepted that I'm going to be under the minimum and short of the code requirement. I'm not really concerned with that since this is likely our "forever home". I agree, flat instead of level would be great but I'm almost certain the undulations in the floor would be noticeable through any flooring type. It's just really uneven which is what initially took me to this idea.

Answer (score 2):

From the AWC's [2018 Manual for Engineered Wood Construction](https://awc.org/publications/2018-manual-for-engineered-wood-construction), OSB's panel shear through-the-thickness strength increases from a minimum value of 155#/in (for 24/0 OSB). Based on your 3" PVC diameter, that's (155#/in)(3.14)(3in) = 1460# punching shear strength, where that's plenty on a 12" grid.

Since the OSB won't have the full joist supports running perpendicular to its strength axis, getting sufficient stiffness and strength out of the OSB sounds analytically tricky. Given your 12" grid, where the 3" PVC implies 9" spans, a */16 span rating intuitively sounds like plenty.

If you want to use fewer PVC stubs, then I would abandon the square grid for a rectangular grid. OSB has a strength axis that makes it substantially stronger when supported on lines running parallel to its short edge. Look at the OSB panel stiffness values from page 52 of the document linked above, where the stiffness in the weak direction is about 1/6 the stiffness in the strong direction. Your grid should simulate as best as possible lines of support running parallel to the short edge of the OSB panels. Standard span ratings are 16" and 24", so those are good spacings for the lines. Along each line, I would put PVC stubs on 9" centers. For the 16" lines you would want */16 rated OSB. For 24" lines you would want */24 rated OSB.

Answer (score 1):

A person who was skilled and experienced in the use of floor leveler could probably get this floor level in short order. The idea of using these PVC rings is interesting to think about but could led to a failed installation.

In Dallas TX some "gotta have real hardwood types" have thick tongue and groove plywood nailed (concrete nails?) to a grade level slab foundation as a nailing subfloor for real hardwood flooring. Yikes! Would an OSB subfloor directly on concrete perform properly in a basement in a cold wet climate?